# Add new format of a book to calibre from command line

Tags: epub, calibre

There are some books with `mobi` and `azw3` formats on my calibre library which I want to convert them to `epub` and I prefer to do it from command line.

I'm able to convert books using `ebook-convert` but I don't know how to add `epub` book to calibre.

`calibredb add` doesn't work since it considers the `epub` as duplicate which is true. But I want to see if there is a way to add the book as a new format to calibre library before messing with calibre `sqlite` db.

I have:

- book id
- epub path

I want:
- to add the epub to an existing entry

Answer (score 2):

Old question but still unanswered, so here is my € 0,02:

Use calibredb add_format [options] id ebook_file

> Blockquote
> Add the e-book in ebook_file to the available formats for the logical book identified by id. You can get id by using the search command. If the format already exists, it is replaced, unless the do not replace option is specified.

source: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/calibredb.html#add-format

So it should be as easy as
calibredb add format epub $ID $epubfile